# Arduino: why does Serial.println(int, HEX) display 4 bytes?

Tags: arduino

An `int` is 2 bytes but Serial.print with HEX or BIN formatting outputs 4 bytes:

```
  int x = 0x9876;
  Serial.println(x, HEX);
  // output is FFFF9876
```

Why?

(and what is a good way to print out only 2 bytes)

Comment: This question would be a better fit for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) possibly with the "embedded" tag.

Comment: It's a fine line. See here: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/how-much-software-is-on-topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Arduino print / println function casts the int to a long, which is 4 bytes long for Arduinos. See here:  https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.cpp

To have more control over printing check out the C++ sprintf function. For example,

```
int x = 0x9876;
char buf[9];
sprintf(buf, "%04x", x);
Serial.println(buf);
```

Will print it out correctly.

sprintf - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/

format string reference - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Some implementations of the `Print` class, include `printf` (Like Adafruit's, see [here](https://github.com/adafruit/ArduinoCore-samd/blob/master/cores/arduino/Print.cpp#L189)). In that case, you just do `Serial.printf("%04X", x)`.

Comment: Based on the source you linked, it seems that println( (unsigned) x ) will also work (casting to unsigned long rather than long).

Comment: Why did you allocated 9 bytes for `buf` variable when `x` fits under 5 bytes?

Answer (score -2):

This is because the data-type 'int' in 'C' language, as per ANSI C standards, is a 32-bit numeric type, and thus you see 4 bytes.

If your variable 'x' can only take 2 byte values, then declare it as a 'short' variable, instead of 'int'. This is because 'short' type as per the language standards is a 16-bit numeric type.

Comment: Arduino ints are 16 bits. According to answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc the C standard says ints have to be able to represent from -32767 to 32767, which is possible in 16 bits.

Comment: Correct ints are 16, the problem as pointed out by geometrikal is that println converts all to longs (32) and println( int ) converts to long. println( unsigned ) will convert to unsigned long, and should do what the OP is expecting.